# Filter out mail with .zip attachments in Thunderbird 24.5

Tags: thunderbird

[Once again](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/zip-attachment-spam-makes-grand-return), spammers and other unsavory folk are sending out malware via attached .zip files.

How can I set up a [message filter](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters) in Thunderbird 24.5 (the current version) that affects only those messages with a .zip file attached?

---

The closest advice I've found so far is a [forum discussion](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2776265) about a method that apparently only works in Thunderbird 23, but it looks like they're filtering based on the presence of ".zip" anywhere in the body text, which isn't quite right.

Comment: @JasonC, that part is easy.  I've just been getting so many of these emails that I'd love to automatically delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird [does not have this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224392). It has been requested for about a decade now but will likely not be implemented due to the reason given in [comment #28](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224392#c28):

> The problem is that attachment name (and for that matter attachment status) is only available after a message has been passed through a MIME parser. Currently, there is no mechanism (even in an extension using custom search terms such as FiltaQuilla) to do MIME processing of a message prior to a search, so information that relies on such a search cannot be used as a search term. This is a major architectural flaw that is not easily remedied.

More information can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=thunderbird+filter+by+attachment+filename).